# Css animation in Chrome Extension doesn't work

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement this animation: http://materializecss.com/preloader.html#circular
in chrome extension.
The problem is: animation doesn't work for some reason:

```
.preloader-wrapper.active {
    -webkit-animation: container-rotate 1568ms linear infinite;
    animation: container-rotate 1568ms linear infinite;
}
```

Why so?

I've checked everything in Inspect popup - all styles and html structure are replicated exactly as in the materialize.

Comment: Could you show me demo of markup so that i can see where is the problem?

Comment: This is working in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/956/ . Just copy the full stylesheet and see if anything is being not applied in the extension

Comment: Thank you, K K, your advice helped

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the animation keyframes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes container-rotate {
to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }

@keyframes container-rotate {
to {transform: rotate(360deg); } }
```

Add these lines and it should work.